# after using preventDefault, why can't i check a box with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How come the following code does not work. I prevent the default action on the event. Then I want to check the box anyway.

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
```

**javsacript**

```
$('.checkbox').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // some logic happens... now i may decide to check the box (in this case we want to check it for testing)
    $('.checkbox').prop('checked',true);
});
```

You would think clicking the checkbox would still check the box.. but it doesnt.  Check the fiddle to see what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/5KDH8/

I have also tried using the `attr` function without any luck.

Comment: I believe click is catcher of by the browser as an onfocus. It will probably work if you click a second time (when it's focussed)?

Comment: Do you have some kind of a server side code that runs when the checkbox is checked as in asp.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the code that sets the "checked" property in a separate event loop:

```
setTimeout(function() { $('.checkbox').prop('checked', true); }, 1);
```

Either the browser or the library has to un-set the checkbox after the event handler returns, because it sets it in response to the click *before* the handler is invoked.

Comment: @Roeland yes I agree; however it's sort-of an odd thing to want to do.  If you want the "click" to end up leaving the checkbox checked, why not just skip calling `.preventDefault()`?

Comment: well in my code there are instances where the checkbox should not be updated by the click.

Comment: @Roeland ah, well you can also call `.preventDefault()` conditionally; that is, only call it when you want the click to leave the checkbox *not* checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.checkbox').click( function(e) {
    // do some logic that returns true or false
    if (!mylogic) {
        return false;
        // returning false will prevent the checkbox to be checked.
    }
});
```