# In jQuery, using e.preventDefault() does not show checkbox status as checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to stop form submission on event click of a checkbox. But unable to show checked state in the UI. I have also tried to use a separate event loop as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15557094/4489470).

First the checkbox will be loaded by ajax, and append as HTML so I had been using on an event

```
discountElement.rentalCompanyWithDiscountDiv
  .on('click', discountElement.rentalCompanyCheckBox, this.loadCamperFromCountryAndRentalCompany);
```

Here is code for adding checked attribute to the HTML and calling another request via ajax

```
loadTakeOverAndReturnableStation: function (e) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            e.target.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
            discountElement.camperIds.push(e.target.value);
        } else {
            e.target.removeAttribute('checked');
            discountElement.camperIds.splice(discountElement.camperIds.indexOf(e.target.value), 1);
        }
        if (discountElement.camperIds.length>0 && discountElement.rentalCompanyIds.length>0){
            var country_id = discountElement.country.val();
            var _token = discountElement._token.val();
            $.ajax({
                url: discountElement.fetchStations.val(),
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': _token
                },
                data: {
                    country_id: country_id,
                    _method: 'POST',
                    'discount_id': discountElement.discountId.val(),
                    'rental_company_id': discountElement.rentalCompanyIds,
                    'camper_id': discountElement.camperIds
                },
                success: discountModule.fillDiv
            });
        }else{
            discountElement.takeOverStationsDiv.empty();
            discountElement.returnableStationsDiv.empty();
        }
}
```

This is my initial state of code which will resubmit form on every click. When I add `e.preventDefault();` It will not show checked state in UI but worked as if it is checked.

When I tried to implement checked state on setTimeout as suggested on the above answer like this

```
e.preventDefault();
setTimeout(function () {
if (e.target.checked) {
    e.target.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
    discountElement.camperIds.push(e.target.value);
} else {
    e.target.removeAttribute('checked');
    discountElement.camperIds.splice(discountElement.camperIds.indexOf(e.target.value), 1);
}
},1);
```

It does not work, either showing checked in the UI or on background,

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? What type is the button this event is listening? Is it a **submit** type button or just a normal button?

Comment: @Ekown it is not a button. It is a checkbox, on click those event will trigger.

Comment: Oh, but why is a form being submitted by a checkbox? It feels weird haha. `preventDefault()` will prevent any default behavior by the event listener including the visible checkmark of the checkbox. https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/